# What are general circuits exactly?

Tags: abe, lwe

This may be a silly question but while reading this paper [Circuit ABE from LWE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/118.pdf), I came across this question on 2nd page - *Is there an ABE scheme for general circuits with unbounded attribute length under standard complexity assumptions?*.

So what exactly are general circuits? My intuition is

Suppose we have $f : {\{0,1}\}^m \rightarrow {\{0,1}\}^n$ . So the circuit implementing this function is a general circuit. Am I right?